# Reverse Box-Cox transformation

Tags: python, statistics, scipy, transformation, inverse

I am using [SciPy's boxcox function](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-dev/reference/generated/scipy.stats.boxcox.html) to perform a [Box-Cox transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_transform#Box.E2.80.93Cox_transformation) on a continuous variable.

```
from scipy.stats import boxcox
import numpy as np
y = np.random.random(100)
y_box, lambda_ = ss.boxcox(y + 1) # Add 1 to be able to transform 0 values
```

Then, I fit a statistical model to predict the values of this Box-Cox transformed variable. The model predictions are in the Box-Cox scale and I want to transform them to the original scale of the variable.

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
rf = RandomForestRegressor()
X = np.random.random((100, 100))
rf.fit(X, y_box)
pred_box = rf.predict(X)
```

**However, I can't find a SciPy function that performs a reverse Box-Cox transformation given transformed data and lambda. Is there such a function?** I coded an inverse transformation for now.

```
pred_y = np.power((y_box * lambda_) + 1, 1 / lambda_) - 1
```

Comment: This seems like a very good question.

Comment: The inverse of the Box-Cox function is in the scipy development version (i.e. the master branch at https://github.com/scipy/scipy), and will be available in release 0.16.  See https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/4211

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to @Warren Weckesser, I've learned that the current implementation of SciPy does not have a function to reverse a Box-Cox transformation. However, a future SciPy release may have this function. For now, the code I provide in my question may serve others to reverse Box-Cox transformations.

Comment: For reference, it's already available here: 
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.special.inv_boxcox.html#scipy.special.inv_boxcox

Comment: @Gyan Veda If we want to use this one from scipy.special like we where using it in scipy.stats, what should we set Lambda to ? I am doing it like this: ``` y_train, self.y_train_lambda_ = boxcox(y_train)``` and lambda is by defualt None, how should I revert in this case?

Comment: @Perl. If you did the boxcox transformation in Scipy the second output argument returned will be lambda. See more in the docs https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.boxcox.html. You can then use that lambda when reversing the transformation.

Answer (score 22):

SciPy has added an inverse Box-Cox transformation.

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.inv_boxcox.html

scipy.special.inv_boxcox
scipy.special.inv_boxcox(y, lmbda) =

Compute the inverse of the Box-Cox transformation.

Find x such that:

```
y = (x**lmbda - 1) / lmbda  if lmbda != 0
    log(x)                  if lmbda == 0
```

Parameters: 
y : array_like

Data to be transformed.

lmbda : array_like

Power parameter of the Box-Cox transform.

Returns:
x : array

Transformed data.

Notes

New in version 0.16.0.

Example:

```
from scipy.special import boxcox, inv_boxcox
y = boxcox([1, 4, 10], 2.5)
inv_boxcox(y, 2.5)

output: array([1., 4., 10.])
```

Comment: Note that if you want to do computations with the predicted value or if you care about the smallest RMSE on the original data, you would want the mean and that has to corrected for bias in the transformation https://otexts.org/fpp2/transformations.html

Comment: @jeffhale why is the values 2.5 passed to boxcox and inv_boxcox method?

Answer (score 14):

1. Here it is the code. It is working and just test. Scipy used neperian logarithm, i check the BoxCox transformation paper and it seens that they used log10. I kept with neperian, because it works with scipy
2. Follow the code:

   ```
   #Function
   def invboxcox(y,ld):
      if ld == 0:
         return(np.exp(y))
      else:
         return(np.exp(np.log(ld*y+1)/ld))

   # Test the code
   x=[100]
   ld = 0
   y = stats.boxcox(x,ld)
   print invboxcox(y[0],ld)
   ```

Answer (score 3):

I recommend to look at Yeo-Johnson transformation, which is Box-Cox analog, but work with negative values and has been well [implemented in scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.PowerTransformer.html) library with easy reverse transformation.

I'm using it with fbprophet library (forecasting):

```py
from sklearn.preprocessing import PowerTransformer

from fbprophet import Prophet
from fbprophet.plot import plot_cross_validation_metric
from fbprophet.diagnostics import cross_validation
from fbprophet.diagnostics import performance_metrics
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def inverse_transform(df, pt_instance, features):
    for feature in features:
        df[feature] = pt_instance.inverse_transform(np.array(df[feature]).reshape(-1,1))
    return df

pt = PowerTransformer(method='yeo-johnson')

train_df_transformed = train_df.copy()
train_df_transformed['y'] = pt.fit_transform(np.array(train_df['y']).reshape(-1,1))

model = Prophet(**hyperparams)
model.fit(train_df_transformed)
df_cv = cross_validation(model, initial='14 days', period='3 days', horizon='1 day', parallel="processes")
df_cv = inverse_transform(df_cv, pt, ['yhat','yhat_lower','yhat_upper'])
df_cv = pd.merge(df_cv.drop(columns=['y']),train_df, left_on='ds', right_on='ds')
df_p = performance_metrics(df_cv, metrics=['mae','mape'], rolling_window=1)
fig1 = plot_cross_validation_metric(df_cv, metric='mape')
fig2 = plot_cross_validation_metric(df_cv, metric='mae')
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to inverse the boxcox transformation from scipy.stats.boxcox using scipy.special.inv_boxcox you have to identify the lambda which was generated.

First apply the transformation and print the lambda (ie. param).

```
df[feature_boxcox], param = stats.boxcox(df[feature])
print('Optimal lambda', param)
```

Then in order to inverse the transformation you input the generated lambda.

```
inv_boxcox(df[feature_boxcox], param)
```