# Generate random data based on existing data

Tags: python, random, statistics, normal-distribution, weibull

is there a way in python to generate random data based on the distribution of the alreday existing data?

Here are the statistical parameters of my dataset:

```
Data
count   209.000000
mean    1.280144
std     0.374602
min     0.880000
25%     1.060000
50%     1.150000
75%     1.400000
max     4.140000
```

as it is no normal distribution it is not possible to do it with np.random.normal. Any Ideas?

[image: Distribution]

Thank you.

Edit: Performing KDE:

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KernelDensity
# Gaussian KDE
kde = KernelDensity(kernel='gaussian', bandwidth=0.525566).fit(data['y'].to_numpy().reshape(-1, 1))
sns.distplot(kde.sample(2400))
```

[image: KDE]

Comment: Take a look at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/215938/generate-synthetic-data-to-match-sample-data also https://towardsdatascience.com/synthetic-data-generation-a-must-have-skill-for-new-data-scientists-915896c0c1ae

Comment: You have 2 options. (1) identify the distribution (chi-square?) and generate it. (2) Do a box cox, generate normal, and then do [reverse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26391454/reverse-box-cox-transformation)

Comment: for option (1): it could also be weibull. how can I be sure about it?. I will try option (2) first. ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, real-world data doesn't exactly follow a "nice" distribution like the normal or Weibull distributions.

Similarly to machine learning, there are generally two steps to sampling from a distribution of data points:

- *Fit* a data model to the data.
- Then, *predict* a new data point based on that model, with the help of randomness.

There are several ways to estimate the distribution of data and sample from that estimate:

- Kernel density estimation.
- Gaussian mixture models.
- Histograms.
- <s>Regression models.</s>
- Other machine learning models.

In addition, methods such as *maximum likelihood estimation* make it possible to fit a known distribution (such as the normal distribution) to data, but the estimated distribution is generally rougher than with kernel density estimation or other machine learning models.

See also my section "[Random Numbers from a Distribution of Data Points](https://peteroupc.github.io/randomfunc.html#Random_Numbers_from_a_Distribution_of_Data_Points)".

Comment: But how shall i perform a Regression model on a single parameter?

Comment: Regression models apply to data that are inputs and outputs (e.g., sales figures for a particular month), which is not the kind of data you've shown here.  For your problem, ignore the advice on regression models.  Perhaps the most promising solution for your data is [kernel density estimation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/density.html), which scikit-learn supports.

Comment: but kde also needs to parameters right? My fit needs a second parameter and i have only one

Comment: What do you mean by "parameters"?

Comment: I see what you mean now:  Kernel density estimation requires a bandwidth parameter, which is roughly the standard deviation of the data points.  See also [this blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20160501200206/http://mark-kay.net/2013/12/24/kernel-density-estimation) for a way to determine this bandwidth parameter using scikit-learn.

Comment: The problem that comes with generating my data this way is: i get values that are below 1 which is not possible for the physical parameter the values are representing. Is there a way to give limitations to a kde estimation? See original post above :)

Comment: You can exclude values below 1 with the following (I didn't test this, since I don't know whether `kde.sample` returns a NumPy array): `s = kde.sample(2400); s = s[s >= 1]`.